# After setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET) the notification channel is still appearing on lockscreen

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, notification-channel

After set a notification channel to not show notifications at lockscreen, it still is showing the notifications on lockscreen.

```
notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET);
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
```

But after the creation of the channel I can debug it and see that the notification channel does not have the lockScreenVisibility set to VISIBILITY_SECRET (-1), it still has the default value, that is -1000.

```
notificationChannel.getLockscreenVisibility()
```

Does anyone knows how to set the lockscreen visibility to not show on lockscreen? Or have any idea why it is not being updated?

One more information is that I already have created the channel previously. But I have deleted and recreated the channel with the VISIBILITY_SECRET.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you delete and recreate a channel, all of the previous settings are restored. You must create a brand new channel (with a different channel ID) or completely uninstall/reinstall the app if you want to change anything other than the channel's name or description.

Comment: Thanks! I also saw on documentation that related to setLockscreenVisibility, seems that it is not possible to be changed by application, the documentation states: "Only modifiable by the system and notification ranker." Do you know anything about it?

Comment: Only the name and description are editable after a channel's creation, hence the note on every other field, `setLockscreenVisibility` included.

Comment: `setLockscreenVisibility` has no effect for me, even after uninstalling the app.

Comment: Same as what @FlorianWalther said. Only works for me if I manually set the visibility for each notification manually. (e.g. NotificationCompat.Builder#setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET)

Answer (score 5):

The reason this may be happening is that even secret notifications are show on the lock screen if the lock screen is not secure (e.g. a PIN is not set):

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.1.0_r33/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/NotificationData.java#521

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me nuts.  In an emulator, I had to enable developer options, prevent 'stay awake' as well.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#setLockscreenVisibility(int)) says that `setLockscreenVisibility` and `setBypassDnd` are "Only modifiable by the system and notification ranker."

The suggestion of @WillNewton works only after you have manually changed this settings.